# Right clicking on files and openning with PyQt application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using the code below for opening and reading text files in pyqt.
But what I want is:
I will choose any text file on my hard disk. Then right click on it and choose open with and browse for my pyqt script and the file will be open
with my sript.

I know that I can do it using 'sys.argv' in terminal. But how to do it with gui program? Please let me know.

Current code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class OpenFile(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('OpenFile')
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.statusBar()
        self.setFocus()
        exit = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('open.png'), 'Open', self)
        exit.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        exit.setStatusTip('Open new File')
        self.connect(exit, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.showDialog)
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        file.addAction(exit)
    def showDialog(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',
                                                     '/home')
        file=open(filename)
        data = file.read()
        self.textEdit.setText(data)
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
cd = OpenFile()
cd.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: that task depends on the OS, you have to register it inside your applications, it would be good to indicate your OS

Comment: I tried that with the script I posted here. But it didn't work. I'm using linux and pcmanfm file manager. I right clicked on a text file, selected open with and browsed for the .py file. Nothing happens.

Comment: @akiksiddique. This is not a programming question, and is therefore off-topic for SO. Please see the section [Run as root](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM#Run_as_root) in the [pcmanfm docs](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM) for some hints about how to solve your problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro, perhaps I couldn't make it clear to you. I'am not looking help for pcmanfm.My code has to be changed for this to work.This is a programming question. I know sys.argv is used in command line programs. How to do it for gui programs? Please read my post again.

Comment: @akiksiddique. There is no difference for gui programs: `sys.argv` works in exactly the same way. What **specific** problem are you not able to solve?

Comment: @ekhumoro, I saw this being used in pyqt: QtGui.QApplication.arguments(). Can't please tell me how it differs with sys.argv?

Comment: @akiksiddique. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36093536/984421).

Comment: @ekhumoro, thank you very much.Its helpful.